# port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, docker, ruby-on-rails-5

Below the versions

- Ubantu 22.04
- rails 5.2.6
- ruby 2.6.10
- postgresql 14

running postgresql in docker container and while running any command like rake db:migrate or trying to connect psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U user or rake db:create gives below error

```
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

and when i try running postgresql locally getting the below error

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Server not found in Kerberos database
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "DATABSE" does not exist
```

Comment: I'd check how your Postgres server is set to authorize external connections and to verify you can connect with a simple tool like `psql` before digging into the Rails side.

Comment: i have used psql -h localhost -U postgres but getting the mentioned error related to GSSAPI

Comment: Check over your `pg_hba.conf` or equivalent to see if that's set up right.

Comment: `FATAL:  database "DATABSE" does not exist` -- what is your connection string (user,host,dbname,port)?

Comment: @richyen i am using user,db_name and port what i have mentioned in docker-compose.yml file, host 127.0.0.1. When I am inside the container and try to do psql with -d template1 it works but outside container from my local machine psql not working.

Answer (score 0):

rake db:migrate does not run directly in the docker container

There are 2 ways to run it

**1) The first one**

First of all, add the following line in the **docker-entrypoint.sh** file

```
echo $SHARED_DIR
bundle exec rake db:setup  DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
bundle exec rake db:migrate  DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

or

```
echo $SHARED_DIR
bundle exec rake db:setup 
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Remember, the rake db:setup command has to be run only once, when you create the Docker image for the first time, after that whenever you create a new image, comment the rake db:setup command.
otherwise, the database will be reset and you will lose your data.

**2) Another way.**

You can go to your project locally and run this command

For that, you have to run the **sudo docker ps -a** command to see all the docker images

After that run to go to the location **sudo docker exec -ti container_id bash** command

then

```
bundle rake db:setup 
bundle rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, but I am not trying to run rake db:migrate inside container, trying from outside.